# Excel: copy data within a column based on duplicate values in another column

Tags: excel

I have a table as:

```
(Column A)Company Name | (Column B)Company Number
ABC                    |    123 
ABC                    |        
CBA                    |        
CBA                    |   234 
ACB                    |   567  
ACB                    |
```

In Column B I need to insert data in row 2 as row 1 (or vice versa) because row 1 and 2 in Column A have same data. The table i have has about 6M such rows and hence looking for some help.

Comment: Your question is very much unclear. Please try making it clearer with the use of some table of picture.

Comment: Please show the desired output -- what do you want the final result to look like?

Comment: By the way, slightly off-topic, but if your dataset has 6M rows, there might be better tools to handle the job than a Spreadsheet (whatever it is -- I still don't understand).  If you don't already have a RDBMS, maybe install an instance of MySQL or PostgreSQL for tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need filters and then just paste the values you need.